# Rational Functional Tester 8.6.0.7 adds 1 second delay to all low-level events (after update)

Tags: functional-programming, keyevent, emit, rft

some time ago we updated our Rational Functional Tester from v8.2.2 to 8.6.0.7. Since this update there is an 1 second delay for all low-level events. But there wasn't a delay before the update. I checked all preferences but could not find a reason for that delay.

The following method for example took ~30 milliseconds before the update and creates now the following system output (in milliseconds):
Time = 0, 1003,2003,3004,4004,5004,6004.

[image: Example Code]

Any idea why this happends?